# How do I change a personal view to a public view?

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library

When you edit a personal view, the radio buttons which were there to select the audience are missing. How do you make a personal view available for other users ?

Comment: can you please point me to an answer ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware whether it's possible to convert a personal view to a public view.

But what you could do is create a new public view that is based on your personal view.

List settings > Create new view > Start from an existing view

Comment: I don't think that's possible. When you create a new view based on the personal view, Still the radio button is disabled.

Comment: That is correct; a personal view cannot be converted to public using normal functionality.  There are apparently 'tricks', though I've not personally tested them: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/77179/how-do-i-create-a-public-view-from-a-private-view